# Java Swing - Updating the view from multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, logging

This question may be duplicated because I found a lot of similar question, but not the answer to my problem: I need to update the view of my SWING application from different SwingWorker.
I have a View class with a JTextArea and a JTable that i need to update during the execution of the Threads. The view also has a Start button that launch all the threads.
The controller listens for the button to be clicked then launch the threads:

```
public class MonitorPageController {

    private MonitorPage monitorPage;
    private List<Mission> missions;

    class StartButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < missions.size(); i++) {
                MyWorker worker = new MyWorker(missions.get(i));
                worker.execute();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then I have MyWorker class that manage the model:

```
public class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

    private Mission m;

    //<dec>
    Block block1 = new Block();
    Block block2 = new block();
    Block block3 = new Block();
    Block block4 = new Block();

    public MyWorker(Mission mission) {
        this.m = mission;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //<exe>
        block1.addObserver(block2);
        block2.addObserver(block3);
        block3.addObserver(block4);
        block4.addObserver(block2);
        block1.update(null, m);

        return 4;
    }

}
```

In the end I have the Block class that is where I need to update the GUI (JTable and JTextArea):

```
public class Block extends Node implements Observer {


    public Mission run(Mission m) {
       m.setStatus(Mission.UNEXECUTED);

       // HERE I WANT TO NOTIGY THE VIEW OF THE CHANGE OF STATUS OF THE MISSION

       return m;
    } 

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Mission m = this.run((Mission) arg);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(m);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Mission is a simple class with the attribute: int status

I already tried with another observer pattern: I setted the mission as observable and the MonitorPageController as the observer. Then in the setter method of the status in class Mission I added the setChanged() and the notifyObservers() methods. In the end in the Observer (MonitoPageController) I implemented the update() method to call the view and update the gui.
I liked this way because it's clean and easy to implement, but I don't now why, after calling the notifyObserver() nothing was happening, so I discarded this solution, even if it seems to be the right one

Comment: Why not create a method that does this in your GUI class? For example, GUIClass.updateText()

Comment: You could use the SwingWorker as proxy between the Blocks and the UI, allowing the SwingWorker to trigger a PropertyChangeEvent or publish the update...

Comment: @CaffeineToCode you mean a static method? I will try it now...
- MadProgrammer look at the edit

Comment: Not necessarily static, but yes a method.

Comment: @Cardella When you implemented Observer in MonitorPageController, in the update() method you update the ui directly or you used   SwingUtilities.invokeLater() ??

Comment: But if it is not static, I would need a reference of the view inside my Block class

Comment: @rafalopez79 I tried with and without...I checked with the method isEventDispatchThread() and it returned me true (inside the MonitorPageController)

Answer (score 1):

Update the UI calling [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) :

```
public class Block extends Node implements Observer {


    public Mission run(Mission m) {
       m.setStatus(Mission.UNEXECUTED);       
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){  
          @Override        
          public void run(){
            //UPDATE UI HERE
          }
       });       
       return m;
    } 

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Mission m = this.run((Mission) arg);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue I would have with this is that it couples the UI to the Node/Block which might not be desirables. A better solution would be to implement another observer pattern which acted as the "status" notification, this way the actual wouldn't care about what you did with the notification. This means you could the. Use the functionality of the SwingWorker's functionality for synchronising the UI, since the op already has one ;)

Comment: as said by MadProgrammer, this solution make me to have the instance of the View in the Block class passing by the SwingWorker. I think there could be better solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution, maybe there better ideas, but this works for now:
Creating the SwingWorker in MonitorPageController I changed the constructor passing the istance of the MonitorPageController too.

```
MyWorker worker = new MyWorker(misssions.get(i), this);
```

Then in MyWorker class when I create Block1, Block2, ...I pass them the istance of the MyWorker:

```
Block block1 = new Block(this);
Block block2 = new Block(this);
....
```

In the same class (MyWorker) I created a method:

```
public void log(Mission m, String s) {
    controller.log(m, s);
}
```

Controller is the istance of the MonitorPageController that created the worker.

Now the inside block class, when I want to notify the change of status, I can call:

```
parentWorker.log(mission, "some string");
```

In the end the log() method in the MonitorPageController calls the view method to update the components...by now it seems to work...